# How can I separate header and footer in twig in Node.Js

Tags: node.js, express, twig

I am trying to dynamic header and footer page but I cannot success. I tried many ways but the header is not loading and I cannot find any sample for Node.Js. No errors occurs but only body content is loaded. All files are at the same directory.

Here the codes are I am tried to.

layout.twig

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US">
..
  <body>
  <header>
    <!-- HEADER -->
    {% block header %}{% endblock %} //Also tried here in index.
  </header>

    {% block body %}{% endblock %}
  </body>
</html>
```

index.twig

```
{% extends 'layout.twig' %}

{% block body %}

    <body>

    <header>
        <!-- HEADER -->
        {% block header %}{% endblock %} //Also tried here in layout.
    </header>
...
{% endblock %}
```

header.twig

```
{% extends 'index.twig' %} //Also tried with {% extends 'layout.twig' %}

{% block header %}
<div class="header js-header js-dropdown">
        <div class="container">
...
{% endblock %}
```

footer.twig is same with header.

EDIT:
Delete extend tags which include on layout.twig and it's solved.

Comment: Can't [reproduce](https://twigfiddle.com/ejqjx3) - Did you clear your cache

Comment: I did. My route renders index view, I updated here https://twigfiddle.com/ejqjx3/2, you can see header contents don't loaded

Comment: That is because you've selected `index.twig` as the main template. Please select `header.twig` and have another look...